# increase the size of the image inside the imageview

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]  [image]

By increasing the image size only the width and height of the `imageview` is getting increased, however i need to increase the actual image i.e add note image not just the background getting increased(as shown in the picture attached)

Moreover i want this clickable image to take the complete width of the phone and 1/3 of the phone's screen height, how is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try something? post your Xml

Comment: <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_note_add_white_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton10"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp" />

Comment: this is my xml,a bit change from the image posted above, but still in this xml the problem is the same as the image inside the imageview is smaller, and as you increse the image view, then only the background size is increased not the whole image, as shown in the picture above...

Comment: @D i have added an answer, see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

for image use: `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

and for 1/3 of the screen use android `weightsum` and `layout_weight`

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

output:

[image]

Comment: is this because of the resolution of the image? should i download with higher dp?

Comment: yes you should use a higher resolution image...as you want to increase it's width and height..Mark the answer as correct if it helps ...thankx

Comment: android:scaleType="fitCenter" is better then fitXY